# Unwanted Space(Gap) is coming between two div's

Tags: html, css

I have two div's .One is image Slider Div and other is footer Div.Now the main problem that is coming is that there is some unwanted space (gap) is coming between these two div's which i don't want.I want both these Div's to be One after another without any space but i am not able to do it.

Here is the HTML ..

```
<div style="padding-top:77px;">
First Slider Div
</div>

<div id="footer" class="footer-shadow">
  Second Footer Div
</div>
```

And here is the css used..

```
.footer-shadow
{
position:relative;
background: url('../img/new_images/footer-bg.png') center center no-repeat;
background-size: contain;
height: 300px;
width: 100%;
color: gray;
}
```

Here is my fiddle link..
[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vikas13pandey/3fyt2xxe/9/)

Please help me to Correct this.Thanks ..

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a gap for me.

Comment: Your demo shows no space between them.

Comment: No space what so ever: http://jsfiddle.net/3fyt2xxe/3/

Comment: @Chrisji but it is coming in my webpage..

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Check you elements inside of the first div there might be someone with margin which is not pushing the parent div down, but the next one. (especially if you have floats)

Comment: @Chrisji Is this because of the image i have added in the backgroun because on seeing it by inspect element i am getting my Footer Staring from the right from the gap till given height..

Comment: I've added a answer that may help if it's a browser issue.

Comment: @drip I have added `  margin-top:-32px;` and now it is diaplaying fine.I have one query as Will be like this in all browsers and screen sizes because same gap was coming in other browsers too.

Answer (score 2):

It is most probably a browser issue, as it's displaying fine for most of us.

A normaliser should help to make all browsers consistent, by overriding the browsers default margins, paddings, etc.

Have a look at [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

Comment: I have added `  margin-top:-32px;` and now it is diaplaying fine.I have one query as Will be like this in all browsers and screen sizes because same gap was coming in other browsers too.

Comment: Hmmm, looks very hacky... I would still suggest using a css normaliser/reseter as it's cleaner.

Comment: Actually footer is starting from there only but background image is not displaying there so it is looking like empty gap.Please help me to display the image from the starting

Comment: Is the gap actually in the image?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vikas13pandey/3fyt2xxe/9/ This is the updated fiddle link ..Here Gap is Visible .please have a look.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vikas13pandey/3fyt2xxe/10/ This fiddle link is with only relevant css..

Comment: In that instance you are setting a padding-top of 45 pixels... `<div id="footerAboutUS" style="float:left; width:150px; position:relative;  margin-left: 10px; padding-top: 45px; line-height: 20px;">`.

Comment: I have added padding-top of 45 pixels so that About Us link should come 45px down to the footer div..Is there any other way to add this and remove my problem.Footer Image should be visible just after the firts Slider Div and About Us link should appear 45px; down to the footer div..

Comment: Sorry, it's still not clear what you want. You say there's a gap between two divs that you don't want, yet you want there to be a gap of 45px between them?

Comment: Ok I will try to be more precise.I have noticed that there is no gap between the Div's and i have noticed that background image is not displaying from the top of the footer Div,it is getting cut there (donno What is the reason) so it is looking like gap .Else every thing is at correct position.So now the issue and Question is Why is footer background image is not displaying from the top (it is getting cut and thats why looking like Gap)

Comment: Again i have noticed one more thing that is i am removing `center center no-repeat` from ` background: url('../img/new_images/footer-bg.png') center center no-repeat;` then the image is coming from the top of the Div but it is getting repetead..

Answer (score 0):

IT looks like normal spacing between divs, but if you want to remove it, try using a negative margin.
Example:
    margin-top: -8;

Comment: I have added `  margin-top:-32px;` and now it is diaplaying fine.I have one query as Will be like this in all browsers and screen sizes because same gap was coming in other browsers too.

Comment: If you want conventional spacing between divs, you should not have to add a -32 px margin for the spacing to display fine. There may be other CSS code rendering the spacing incorrectly, or as posted in other answers, it could be a browser issue. 

I would try different browsers, and dig through the rest of your CSS to see if there are any discrepancies. 

Unless, of course, your goal is to have unconventional spacing between divs.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vikas13pandey/3fyt2xxe/9/  This is my updated fiddle link.Here You can See the space..Please have a look

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vikas13pandey/3fyt2xxe/10/ This fiddle link is with only relevant css

Comment: Is your goal to have "About Us" just below the black rectangle? That is the only large amount of space that I am seeing. If this is the case, remove the padding-top: 45px; from the style of div with id="footerAboutUS"

Comment: I have added padding-top of 45 pixels so that About Us link should come 45px down in the footer div..Is there any other way to add this and remove my problem.Footer Image should be visible just after the firts Slider Div and About Us link should appear 45px; down to the footer div..

Comment: Also i have noticed one more thing if i am removing padding-top:45px; then My About Us is displaying at top of the footer Div removing the gap but my background image is still diaplying there only.So i think that issue is with Background image of the footer..

Comment: Again i have noticed one more thing that is i am removing center center no-repeat from ` background: url('../img/new_images/footer-bg.png') center center no-repeat;` then the image is coming from the top of the Div but it is getting repetead..

Comment: Post the entire code to JSFiddle if possible, and use the full url path to the background image. Currently, I am not able to understand what you are trying to accomplish.